# How to represent a permutation in cycle form notation in C++?

Tags: c++, permutation, cycle

The description of the problem is this. I have `1` to `k` distinct variables (for example `1`: faces of a cube, `2`: vertices of a cube) and `1` to `n_k` instances of each variable (continuing the example above, `n_1 = 6`, for each face of the cube and `n_2 = 8` for each face of the cube). There is then a permutation group defining valid permutations of the instances of the variables. As a concrete example, we have for the cube permutation group, where `f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6` are the six faces (`f` is variable 1) and `v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8` are the 8 faces (`v` is variable 2). Then some examples of valid permutations are

```
G = {e, (f1)(f2 f3 f4 f4)(f6)(v1 v2 v3 v4)(v5, v6, v7, v8) ...}
```

Don't worry about finding the permutation group or how to decide which face corresponds to which `fi` or which vertex to which `vj`. The point is that even though array notation is convenient to store a permutation programmaticly (`vector<vector<int>> arr` with `arr[j][i]` corresponding to the value that permuted to position `i` of variable `j`), I need to be able to quickly determine what elements are in a which cycle. Like in the example above, `f2, f3, f4,` and `f5` are all in one cycle.

To do this I'd like to store them in a representation of cycle notation in C++. I can't think of a good way (`vector<vector<vector<int>>>` is all I've got, since I'm not actually interested in storing the names of the variables, just distinguishing between them) to represent this. A fast way to calculate this or a good way to store it would be helpful.

I know this isn't the most clear explanation ever, so feel free to ask for clarifications.

Comment: Why include different variables in the problem? It looks like they are independent and the problem is equivalent to a bunch of small problems with one variable each.

Comment: Even though the vertices are never included in the same cycles as the faces, a permutation of the faces permutes the vertices in a specific way, and it matters that they are matched up in such a way, so when I output the answer I have a position for the vertices relative to the position of the faces.
I removed my previous answer because this one seemed clearer. Let me know if there is anything I can be clearer about.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `arr[j][i] corresponding to the value that permuted to position i of variable j`... Usually when I store a permutation, I use a single vector:  `vector<int>(3,1,2)` denote the function 1->3, 2-> 1, 3-> 2. Why a vector<vector<int>> ?

Comment: I use a vector<vector<int>> because I want to distinguish between types of permuting objects, like the faces and the vertices of the cube. As a concrete example, arr[0] is a vector corresponding to the permutation of the faces and arr[1] is a vector corresponding to the permutation of the vertices. arr[0][1] is the position that face 2 moves to. Make sense?